# A homework problem about set theory

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Assume $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_{10}\}$, each $9<a_i<100$ ,then prove that there exists set B and C such that $A=B \cup C$ , $B \cap C = \emptyset$ and the elements' sum in B is equal to C's.

I am thinking that A has 1024 different subsets and the sum of each subset is no larger than 1000 which shows that there must be two sets B and C that their sums are equal, but I can't prove that they are disjoint and cover A.

Edit:  This problem is itself wrong by discussion , let we look at another question : Use the same situation with the last problem, then will there exist two different partitions by two subsets such that they have the same sum on each subset?

Comment: I think this is false. Consider 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26. The end sum is odd and so cannot be partitioned in 2.

Comment: Are you sure you have the details of the question right?

Comment: @arthur perhaps each set element must be distinct.  I think somewhere this question was mangled.  There are 1024 ways to partition the sets (well, 512, but I think that was part of the mangling) and 910 different sums so ... oh, i don't know what the question was supposed to be.

Comment: I imagine the question is probably there exist two different partitions which both have the same sums for B and C.

Comment: @fleablood emmmm, I think maybe this problem is wrong, and can you prove your statement?

Comment: @IntegrateThis it's the complete question, maybe it's wrong

Comment: @fleablood's alternative question is probably right.

Comment: @IntegrateThis The alternative is certainly right, maybe we can prove like I said in the question statement?

Comment: @R.Sherlock edit the question and I will work on it tomorrow lol.

Comment: @IntegrateThis okay thanks a lot!

Comment: Proving my interpretation is easy with Pigeon hole principal.  There are $1024$ partitions.  The sum of A is at least 100 and at most 1000 and the number of possible sums of B can not be more than the actual sum of A.  And as C = $\overline B$ the sum of A fixes the some of B.  So... Pigeonhole two of the 1024 ways to partition A most be the same of fewer than 100 sums. *HOWEVER* this assume B=K; C=$\overline K$ is a different partition than B=$\overline K$; C=K.  If order doesn't matter (I don't think it should), then there are 512 partions... to be continue....

Comment: But if order doesn't count and there are $512$ ways to choose A, I still think this is probably true there are probably fewer than $512$ sums from the same 10 numbers.  That might be a little trickier to prove.  I suspect that it will have something to do with highest possible value of 100 is less than 2^7 so any sum with more than seven terms can be formed in more than 1 way... Oh, that might be it.  It might have nothing to do with with 512 partitions.  I'll need to think about it.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the sum of $A$ is odd, then we can't partition $A$ into $B$ and $C$ such that they have the same sum.

Comment: There is no such supposition in the question. All you did was prove that the sum of A is even.

Comment: @DanSp.  Huh??  So se's with odd sums don't exist or are impossible to prove exist?  If $A = \{10,12,14,16,18,20 , 22, 24,26,99\}$ then the statement certainly isn't true.  And a counter example disproves a statement.

Comment: But if we suppose the sum of A is even? Will this question be right

Comment: No, we can do all but one of the ten numbers is a multiple of $3$, or $4$, or $5$, or..  The stipulations to avoid cases will be more complicated and difficult to express than the solution.